# TFS Online. Create code review on developer checkin before it get merged into codebase

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Is there anyway to setup some 'workflow' in which when a developer do a checkin, there's a requirement to code review that may go back to developer (if there's something to change) or get accepted and go with the checkin. That would be a development branch.

No checkin should be accepted if (Code Review wasn't accepted. It does not build, It has not passed unit tests).

How and where to configure this things?

Comment: Since you're calling it a Commit and not a Check-in, are we talking Git or TFVC here?

Comment: Sorry, we are talking TFVC. updated to say check-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code review check-in policy you can use "Colin's ALM Checkin Policies" -

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078

This should satisfy what you are looking for but if not then you can write a custom check-in policy. Check below URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

For your other part of the question you an use Gated check-in to make sure the code compiles and all unit tests pass before code gets checked-in. See below images on how to set that up. You can go to this URL to understand how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do we do it for Visual Studio Online

Comment: Colin's ALM Checkin Policies would work for TFS Online, but needs to be installed on every client box

Answer (score 0):

By default there is none. You  can build a custom checkin policy to require this